# onPostExecute() getting value for last json object only

Tags: java, android, json

I have successfully `parsed JSON` and getting value for both the objects like: image, period in **AsyncTask**, but in `onPostExecute()` method i am getting `value` for `last json object` only.

here i am getting only last object value for period :

```
 delay, period); // getting last object's period value only
```

What could be the reason, why i am getting only last object value for period object in onPostExecute() method

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> actorsList;
    ViewFlipper viewFlipper;    
    Handler mHandler ;
    Timer timer;
    Runnable mUpdateResults;
    int delay = 500;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);

        actorsList = new ArrayList<String>();

        // execute AsyncTask
        new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://localhost/images.txt");

        // handler to set duration and to upate animation
        mHandler = new Handler();

        // Create runnable for posting
        mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                viewFlipper.showNext(); // showNext() method
            }
        };

        timer = new Timer();        
    }

    // AsyncTask to get data from server
    class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        int period;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                //------------------>>
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("images");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        actorsList.add(object.getString("image"));
                        Log.d("image: ", object.getString("image"));                        
                        try {
                            period = Integer.parseInt(object.getString("period").toString());
                            Log.d("period: ", object.getString("period"));
                        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                            System.out.print("could not parse:" + nfe);
                        }                       
                    }
                    return true;
                }

            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(result == false)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {           
            for(int i=0; i<actorsList.size(); i++)
            {
                ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());              

                Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                .load(actorsList.get(i).toString())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .into(image);

                viewFlipper.addView(image); // addView(..) method
            }           

             Log.d("period:post- ", String.valueOf(period));
             timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                public void run() {
                    mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
                }
            }, delay, period); // getting last object's period value only

          }
       }
    }
}
```

**Logcat:**

```
10-10 11:46:52.527: D/image:(542): http://localhost/image_01.jpg
10-10 11:46:52.536: D/period:(542): 50000
10-10 11:46:52.536: D/image:(542): http://localhost/image_05.jpg
10-10 11:46:52.536: D/period:(542): 5000
10-10 11:46:52.536: D/image:(542): http://localhost/image_06.jpg
10-10 11:46:52.536: D/period:(542): 5000
10-10 11:46:52.546: D/image:(542): http://localhost/image_07.jpg
10-10 11:46:52.546: D/period:(542): 25000
10-10 11:46:52.546: D/image:(542): http://localhost/image_08.jpg
10-10 11:46:52.546: D/period:(542): 5000
10-10 11:46:52.546: D/image:(542): http://localhost/image_02.jpg
10-10 11:46:52.556: D/period:(542): 5000
10-10 11:46:52.556: D/image:(542): http://localhost/image_03.jpg
10-10 11:46:52.556: D/period:(542): 1000
10-10 11:46:52.556: D/image:(542): http://localhost/image_04.jpg
10-10 11:46:52.566: D/period:(542): 1000
10-10 11:46:52.616: D/period:post-(542): 1000
```

Comment: in your logcat how many times image: is printed ?

Comment: @Nooh I have posted my log please check now

Answer (score 0):

Because in this loop:

```
       for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    actorsList.add(object.getString("image"));
                    Log.d("image: ", object.getString("image"));                        
                    try {
                        period = Integer.parseInt(object.getString("period").toString());
                        Log.d("period: ", object.getString("period"));
                    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        System.out.print("could not parse:" + nfe);
                    }                       
                }
```

when it finishs your `period` is equal to last `json` that you parsed.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> actorsList;
    ViewFlipper viewFlipper;    
    Handler mHandler ;
    Timer timer;
    List<Integer> periodsList;
    Runnable mUpdateResults;
    int delay = 500;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        periodsList=new ArrayList<Integer>();

        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);

        actorsList = new ArrayList<String>();

        // execute AsyncTask
        new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://localhost/images.txt");

        // handler to set duration and to upate animation
        mHandler = new Handler();

        // Create runnable for posting
        mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                viewFlipper.showNext(); // showNext() method
            }
        };

        timer = new Timer();        
    }

    // AsyncTask to get data from server
    class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        int period;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                //------------------>>
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("images");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        actorsList.add(object.getString("image"));
                        Log.d("image: ", object.getString("image"));                        
                        try {

                            period = Integer.parseInt(object.getString("period").toString());
                            periodsList.add(Integer.parseInt(object.getString("period").toString()));
                            Log.d("period: ", object.getString("period"));
                        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                            System.out.print("could not parse:" + nfe);
                        }                       
                    }
                    return true;
                }

            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(result == false)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {           
            for(int i=0; i<actorsList.size(); i++)
            {
                ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());              

                Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                .load(actorsList.get(i).toString())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .into(image);

                viewFlipper.addView(image); // addView(..) method
            }           


            int mDelay = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<periodsList.size(); i++)
            {
             Log.d("period:post- ", String.valueOf(periodsList.get(i)));
             timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                public void run() {
                    mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
                }
            }, mDelay);

            mDelay = mDelay  + periodsList.get(i);

          }
         }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: so where i have to make change ?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: have you read my Logcat, especially last line: 10-10 11:46:52.616: D/period:post-(542): 1000 why i am not getting post value for all json objects

Comment: where you made changes in my code, will you highlight me that, so i will make change on that point only

Comment: getting NPE here: periodsList.add(Integer.parseInt(object.getString("period").toString()));

Comment: replace it by `periodsList.add(new Integer(period));`

Comment: At the end your logic is wrong and you can not create a `slid show` with `scheduleAtFixedRate` because it runs a task at a specific time repeatedly but your period for showing an image is different image by image, so I changed it and use all of the period to start next task at the right time, good luck

Comment: still getting NPE here: periodsList.add(new Integer(period));

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a another Arralist.

in this list you just add periods(like you did for actorsList)

mainclass add

```
ArrayList<Integer> periods;
```

in onCreate()

```
periods=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

in doInBackground

```
try {
     periods.add(Integer.parseInt(object.getString("period").toString()));

    Log.d("period: ", object.getString("period"));
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    System.out.print("could not parse:" + nfe);
}
```

Comment: why i have to make another arraylist ?'

Comment: every time you parse JSON object,variable period is replaced. that reason you get last period only

Comment: its like you created a arraylist for actorsList.if you don't created an list for Actors you got only last actor image url @Sophie